# String method of reflect.Value does not work as expected

Tags: reflection, go

I'm trying to retrieve the string value from a reflect.Value,

I expect `value.String()` to be `okok` but I got `<interface {} Value>` instead.

Did I miss something?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func dump(args *[]interface{}) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(*args).Index(0)
    fmt.Println(value.String())
    if value.String() != "okok" {
        fmt.Println("miss")
    }
}

func main () {
    var args []interface{}
    args = append(args, "okok")
    dump(&args)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for Value.String](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.String) explains the behavior:

> Unlike the other getters, it does not panic if v's Kind is not String.
>   Instead, it returns a string of the form "<T value>" where T is v's
>   type.

String is just an implementation of the fmt.Stringer interface.

If you want the value itself, you can use the [Interface function](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) on reflect.Value and then do a type assertion to get the string. Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func dump(args *[]interface{}) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(*args).Index(0)
    str := value.Interface().(string)
    fmt.Println(str)
    if str != "okok" {
        fmt.Println("miss")
    }
}

func main() {
    var args []interface{}
    args = append(args, "okok")
    dump(&args)
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/vVlD5H26iD)